# Greedy approach suggestions for assigning objects

Tags: algorithms, np-complete, greedy-algorithms

Suppose there are three categories of people.
Type X, Type Y, Type Z.
In each type, there are two objects of subtype Type 'a' and type 'b'.

For example.

X: a1 , a2 , b1 , b2

Y: a3 , a4 , b3 , b4

Z: a5 , a6 , b5 , b6

Each object of type 'a' should be assigned with an object of type 'b'. But it is ****desirable** not necessary** to assign a type 'a' with type 'b' from different classes (X, Y, Z).

In this example, the optimal solution would be:
a1 with b5 ,
a2 with b6 ,
a3 with b1 ,
a4 with b2 ,
a5 with b3 ,
a6 with b4 .

Non -optimal solution would be :

a1 with b5 ,
a2 with b6 ,
a5 with b1 ,
a6 with b2 ,
a3 with b3 ,
a4 with b4 .

(Non -optimal because a3 and a4 are assigned with b's of same type Y)

If we generalize, there can be n- number of Types (X,Y,Z, .....and so on) with different number of a's and b's in each (but total number of a's = total number of  b's).

How to find an optimal solution?

Comment: How do you measure "optimality"?  Is it the number of matches between two objects of a different type?  Do you require that all objects be matched? Can you state the task a bit more precisely?

Comment: @D.W. yes, optimality  is the number of matches between two objects of a different type.

Comment: and yes, all objects have to be matched.

Answer (score 1):

This problem reduces to finding a maximum matching in a bipartite graph, which can be done easily by e.g. the Ford-Fulkerson algorithm. You construct the graph as follows:

Take all elements of type $a$ on one side and all elements of type $b$ on the other. Then, for any two elements $a_i,b_j$, draw an edge between them if they do not belong to the same category.

If there is a matching in the set with only, say, $k$ pairs belonging to the same category, then we can find a matching in our graph on $m-k$ edges, where $m$ is the number of a's (or b's).